# Timepicker issue with defaultTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

i am using time picker my code and options are given below :

```
var options = {timeFormat: 'h:mm p', interval: 15, maxTime: '11:45pm', startTime: '12:00', defaultTime: new Date(),dynamic: true, dropdown: true, scrollbar: true}

$('.end_time,.start_time').timepicker(options);
```

it is returning me the output like :

it is working fine but it starts from the current time .what i want is i want it to start from 12:00am and end to 11:45pm like teams and google calender timepicker.

like that

[this is what i actually want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF55Z.png)

[from my timpicker i am getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPWR8.png)

Hello Ananad this is what i am taliking about:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jonxr.png)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var options = {timeFormat: 'h:mm p', interval: 15,minTime:"00:00am", maxTime: '11:45pm',  defaultTime: new Date(), startTime: '00:00am',dynamic: false, dropdown: true, scrollbar: true}

$('#time').timepicker(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<input id="time" />
```

Does this answer's your question. I had put dynamic as false as it was arranging result in chronological order.

Comment: its working all cool except one thing selcted date should be display in dropdown. on every click it is starting from start

Comment: like if i am selecting 5:45 PM and again click dropdown showing me from 12:00 Am instead of this i want it to display the selected time.

Comment: Check your code. Mine is working correctly when selected

Comment: I have uploaded the image on my question because i cant post it here .. i have selected 1:30PM  but it is displaying the dropdown from the starting.